# How to create a reusable function in Node without writing boilerplate code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express.js as http server. Defined all my routes.

Most endpoints need to verify session before returning a response. E.g. below code serves users in the system and list of services respectively:

```
function getUsers(req, res, next) {
  verifyUser(req, res, next, function () {
      //serve users
  });
}

function getServices(req, res, next) {
  verifyUser(req, res, next, function () {
    //serve services
  });
}
```

You probably noticed there is a verifyUser function which validates the session. Which is as below.

```
function verifyUser(req, res, next, callback) {
  var sessionKey = req.cookies.sessionKey;
  var user = users.userBySession(sessionKey);
  if (user) {
    callback(req, res, next, user);
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({
      message: 'Unauthorized'
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see I keep  passing in req, res and next parameters along with a callback whenever I use this function.

I tried to use apply function to make it easier. Changed my getUsers function like this:

```
function getUsers(req, res, next) {
  verifyUser
    .apply(null, arguments, function () {
      //serve users
    });
}
```

The problem with this approach is callback is not passed into verifyUser function. And I don't really like passing null as scope with each call.

How can I achieve this by writing less and better code ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `bind` to create a 'partial function':

```
// create bound responseHelper object
var responseHelper = verifyUser.bind(null, req, res, next);

// usage
responseHelper(getUsersCallback); // same as verifyUser(req, res, next, getusersCallBack);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to turn `verifyUser` into a middleware function.

```
function verifyUser (req, res, next) {
  var user = // yadda yadda session stuff
  if (user) {
    req.user = user; // [1] what you do to the req object here...
  } else {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "No way Smokey Joe"});
    /**
     * alternatively, do something like

     * var err = new Error("Not authorized");
     * err.statusCode = 401;
     * return next(err);
     * 
     * this will kick off Express' error handling mechanism, 
     *   which you should read about in the docs (see the link below)
     */
  }

  next(); 
  // very important to call next after this verifyUser has done its job
  // if you don't, the next middleware won't go off,
  //   and the request will just hang
}

function getUsers (req, res, next) {
    // [2] will show up on the req object here, assuming you chain these
    // two functions together as middleware
}

app.get("/users", verifyUser, getUsers);
app.get("/services", verifyUser, getServices);

// here's a route that needs no session auth, so no need to verifyUser
app.get("/latest-posts", getLatestPosts);
```

When you tell Express to `use` a function or attach a function to a route path via `get('/my/route', hanlderFun)` or some such, you've basically turned `handlerFun` into a middleware.

You can define however many middleware as handlers on a route as you like, and they'll all execute in turn as long as you keep calling `next`.

```
app.post("/checkout", verifyUser, tallyCart, checkInventory, doPayment, sendInvoice);
```

The job of `next` is to pass control from the current middelware to the next one. It's an object

You can do other stuff with `next`, too, which you should read up on in the docs.

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

The docs on routing have good info on middleware as well:

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

For extra credit, check out error handling middleware, too:

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I should definitely use middleware function. Though I guess the question suggests I was looking for a solution for this particular express js problem. I actually meant to ask how to achieve something like this in general with Javascript. Still thanks for this.

Comment: No problem. Doing this in a more general way is tricky. You could explore converting `arguments` into an array and pushing your callback into it. Probably not worth the work, though, since you'd be typing just as much. It'd make your code a bit less clear, too.

Maybe check out a functional toolkit like Ramda. You might find a convenient helper that would facilitate some sort of incremental partial application something or other.

Thinking more about it, I don't know of a way to do this that isn't more complicated than its worth. You never know until you try, though. Good luck!